# TP-link router firmware upgrade needs reset to factory default settings

Tags: router, firmware

About to upload a new firmware to my router (tp-link wd8961), I read this in the instructions:

> You have to restore the device to factory default to make the new
>   functions take effect.

There are no new functions advertised. Only a non-specific security fix is provided.

Since factory reset means that I will lose all my settings, I'd rather not do this. Does it mean the security fix may also not be activated? What exactly happens during firmware upgrade? Is the new firmware only activated with this factory reset or is the quote above just a copy&paste phrase coming with all upgrades, just in case?

Comment: I think only tp-link can answer that question. Ask their support http://uk.tp-link.com/support-contact.html

Comment: Firmware should be activated with a reset (not default), but if the settings changed (which could be a behind the scenes setting for the security fix), it may not become effective until you factory reset, restoring the default configuration file. This is a simple wireless router, all you really need to change is the WiFi security & SSID, and maybe some port forwarding or ISP settings, is it really that difficult? This should only take a minute or two.

Comment: From what I read on tp links site (V4 hardware) " Your device's configuration won't be lost after upgrading, which means you needn't configure your device again after upgrading."...http://www.tp-link.com/en/download/TD-W8961ND.html#Firmware

Comment: There are 4 hardware versions of that Model, which one do you have?

Comment: @Moab: it is V3.0.

Comment: "You have to restore the device to factory default to make the new functions take effect." Where did you see this?

Comment: On http://www.tp-link.com/en/download/TD-W8961ND_V3.html#Firmware the V3_150707 download contains a PDF which contains this statement.